# TCL: How to convert a hex value to signed integer?

Tags: hex, tcl, decimal, data-conversion

This command assumes that the hex represents unsigned value:

```
set q 0xffffb764
set r [expr $q]
puts $r
```

Is there a simple way to make it treat q as representing a signed value rather than an unsigned value?

Comment: This is your 3rd question in a row that is a variation on the same theme. Maybe you could try to find the solution yourself based on the answers to the previous questions?

Comment: What value do you want to see in $r?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my solution:

```
  proc hex_to_signed {value} {
    set sign [expr {($value & 0b10000000000000000000000000000000)}]
    set mag  [expr {($value & 0b01111111111111111111111111111111)}]
    if {$sign==0} {
      set exp 0
    } else {
      set exp [expr -2**31]
    }       
    set value [expr {$exp + $mag}]
    return $value
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution using format

```
set q 0xffffb764
set r [format "%d" $q]
puts $r
```